# Swapping panels in a frame

Tags: java, panel, frame

So i have a frame and 2 panels, originally panel A is displayed in the frame. i have got it set up so when a button is clicked in the panel it makes a call back to the frame and runs this bit of code. ("splash" is the panel that is originally displayed and "game" is the panel i want to show after the button press)

```
public void startGame()
{
    System.out.println("starting game");
    remove(splash);

    gameThread = new Thread(game, "game thread");
    gameThread.start();
    add(game);

    /*
    this.setSize(0,0);
    this.setSize(450, 450);
    */
}
```

anyways this seems to remove the one panel fine but wont display the second panel until you resize the window. the commented section seems to solve this problem but i cant help think there is a better way to do this. i have surfed the API and haven't found anything helpful.

if anyone knows a better way, or has run into this problem. please share your knowledge, this one has me stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Michael pointed out CardLayout is a good way to go.

The specific functionality you are looking for is [Container.validate()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#validate%28%29).  It will "cause the container to lay out its subcomponents again.  It should be invoked when this container's subcomponents are modified ... after the container has been displayed."

Comment: Thanks, i knew it was something simple that i was overlooking. just couldn't put my finger on it. the program works like a charm now.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [CardLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for this kind of thing instead of removing and adding panels.

Answer (score 1):

The container holding the panels needs to be invalidated, validated and repainted (all on EDT). For example, if the frame is the holder then

```
frame.invalidate();
frame.validate();
frame.repaint();
```

This is of course after the target panel has been added.

Comment: If you're going to call validate() on a container that has changed its layout, you don't need either invalidate or repaint.

Comment: In my experience, it was required -- just invoking validate didn't do the trick.

Comment: @01es as long as the container has changed its layout, it will have called invalidate internally already.  Part of the validate process is that if the container needs to be repainted, it will call repaint.  You won't hurt anything by doing it your way, but it's just unnecessary method calls.

Comment: The javadoc for validate states "If this Container is not valid, this method invokes the validateTree method and marks this Container as valid. Otherwise, no action is performed.". So, in case the container is valid (for some reason in my case it was valid) it has to be invalidated first.

Comment: @01es removing a child component with remove(...) causes the container to be marked invalid.  But you are right, in your case if you are doing custom painting with paintComponent, or something that does not auto invalidate the container... absolutely, you should call invalidate on the component first.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, i really don't remember how since i haded the same problem you have, but, have you try to use:

```
this.setVisible(true);
```

That might work